# Executing several SQL queries with MySQLdb

Tags: python, sql, batch-processing, sql-scripts

How would you go about executing several SQL statements (script mode) with python?

Trying to do something like this:

```
import MySQLdb
mysql = MySQLdb.connect(host='host...rds.amazonaws.com', db='dbName', user='userName', passwd='password')
sql = """
insert into rollout.version (`key`, `value`) VALUES ('maxim0', 'was here0');
insert into rollout.version (`key`, `value`) VALUES ('maxim1', 'was here1');
insert into rollout.version (`key`, `value`) VALUES ('maxim2', 'was here1');
"""
mysql.query(sql)
```

Fails with:

> ProgrammingError: (2014, "Commands out
>   of sync; you can't run this command
>   now")

I'm writing an deployment engine that would accept SQL delta changes from several people and apply them to the DB on version deployment.

I've looked into this code http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2009/02/python-sql-runner.html and implemented __sanitize_sql:

```
def __sanitize_sql(sql):
    # Initial implementation from http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2009/02/python-sql-runner.html
    sql_statements = []

    incomment = False
    in_sqlcollect = False

    sql_statement = None
    for sline in sql.splitlines():
        # Remove white space from both sides.
        sline = sline.strip()

        if sline.startswith("--") or len(sline) == 0:
            # SQL Comment line, skip
            continue

        if sline.startswith("/*"):
            # start of SQL comment block
            incomment = True
        if incomment and sline.endswith("*/"):
            # end of SQL comment block
            incomment = False
            continue

        # Collect line which is part of 
        if not incomment:
            if sql_statement is None:
                sql_statement = sline
            else:
                sql_statement += sline

            if not sline.endswith(";"):
                in_sqlcollect = True

            if not in_sqlcollect:
                sql_statements.append(sql_statement)
                sql_statement = None
                in_sqlcollect = False

    if not incomment and not sql_statement is None and len(sql_statement) != 0:
        sql_statements.append(sql_statement)

    return sql_statements

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sql = sql = """update tbl1;
/* This
is my
beautiful 
comment*/
/*this is comment #2*/
some code...;
-- comment
sql code
"""
    print __sanitize_sql(sql)
```

Don't know if it's the best solution but seems to work for not too complex to parse SQL statements.

The question now how to run this code, I can do something like [this dude](http://eric.lubow.org/2009/python/pythons-mysqldb-2014-error-commands-out-of-sync/) but it seems ugly, I'm not a python expert (we've been doing python here for just the past 2 weeks) but it seems that abusing cursor this way is hackish and not a good practice.

Ideas / blog posts would be helpful.

Thanks you,
Maxim.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you could use `executemany()`:

```
import MySQLdb
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host='host...rds.amazonaws.com', db='dbName', user='userName', passwd='password')
cursor = connection.cursor()

my_data_to_insert = [['maxim0', 'was here0'], ['maxim1', 'was here1'], ['maxim2', 'was here1']]
sql = "insert into rollout.version (`key`, `value`) VALUES (%s, %s);"

cursor.executemany(sql, my_data_to_insert)

connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Call the executemany method on the cursor object. More info here:
http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html