# MySQLdb.cursors.Cursor.execute does not work

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have done the following:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect(hostname, username, password, dbname)
cur = con.cursor()
count = cur.execute(query)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

I have two queries, I execute them in the mysql console I can view the results.
But when I give the same through python one query works and the other one does not.
I am sure it is not problem with mysql or query or python code. I suspect **cur.execute(query)** function.

Have anyone come through similar situation? Any solutions?

Comment: did you replace hostname, username, password and dbname with actual values? @JayakumarBellie

Comment: And are we supposed to guess what the non-working query is?

Comment: exactly @DanielRoseman

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi ya I give the actual values.

Comment: This is a function and the query is passed to this function. When I execute one query after the other. I dont get the result for few queries, there is no problem with the queries because I have crossed checked them with the mysql console.

Answer (score 15):

Use **conn.commit()** after execution, to commit/finish insertion and deletion based changes.

Comment: Or set `con.autocommit(True)` after connecting. This is what worked well for me. I don't know why, but `con.commit()` didn't.

Answer (score 0):

> I have two queries, I execute them in the mysql console I can view the results.

But I only see *one* query:

```
import MySQLdb as mdb
con = mdb.connect(hostname, username, password, dbname)
cur = con.cursor()
count = cur.execute(query)
cur.close()
con.close()
```

My *guess* is `query` contains the *both* queries separated by a semin-colon *and* is an `INSERT` statement? You probably need to use `executemany()`.

See [Executing several SQL queries with MySQLdb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4615271/executing-several-sql-queries-with-mysqldb)

---

On the other hand, if both of your queries are `SELECT` statements (you say "I *see* the result"), I'm not sure you can fetch both results from only one call to `execute()`. I would consider that as bad style, anyway.

Comment: No it is separate queries. When I execute one query after the other. I dont get the result for few queries, there is no problem with the queries because I have crossed checked them with the mysql console.

Answer (score 0):

> **This is a function and the query is passed to this function.** When I
>   execute one query after the other. I dont get the result for few
>   queries, there is no problem with the queries because I have crossed
>   checked them with the mysql console.

As you clarified your question in a comment, I post an other answer -- completely different approach.

Are you connected to your DB in autocommit mode? If no, for changes to be permanently applied, you have to [`COMMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) them. In *normal* circumstances, you shouldn't create a new connection for each request. That put excessive load on the DB server for almost nothing:

```python
# Open a connection once
con = mdb.connect(hostname, username, password, dbname)


# Do that *for each query*:
cur = con.cursor()
try:
    count = cur.execute(query)
    conn.commit() # don't forget to commit the transaction
else:
    print "DONE:", query # for "debug" -- in real app you migth have an "except:" clause instead
finally:
    cur.close() # close anyway


# Do that *for each query*:
cur = con.cursor()
try:
    count = cur.execute(query)
    conn.commit() # don't forget to commit the transaction
else:
    print "DONE:", query # for "debug" -- in real app you migth have an "except:" clause instead
finally:
    cur.close() # close anyway


# Close *the* connection
con.close()
```

The above code is directly typed into SO. Please forgive typos and other basic syntax errors. But that's the spirit of it.

A last word, while typing I was wondering how you deal with exceptions? By any chance could the MySQLdb error be silently ignored at some upper level of your program?

Answer (score 0):

Use this query, this will update multiple rows of column in one query

```
sql=cursor.executemany("UPDATE `table` SET `col1` = %s WHERE `col2` = %s",
            [(col1_val1, col2_val1),(col2_val2, col_val2)])
```

and also commit with database to see the changes.

```
conn.commit()
```